# i have an issue with mobile first 6.3 javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

**an error happened while calling IBM mobile first adapter**

```
[ERROR  ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure [project DM]MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E: parameters: [project DM]  Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty  FWLSE0101E: Caused by: [project DM]javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-emptyjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:236)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:185)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:169)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:145)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:134)  at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)  at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:593)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:539)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:58)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:433)  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:430)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:496)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:480)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:131)  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor208.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)  at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_12(/integration.js:103)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2019_01_20T15_38_23_907Z_6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b_MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter_impl_js_11._c_registerPublicUser_5(2019-01-20T15:38:23.907Z/6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b/MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter-impl.js:74)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2019_01_20T15_38_23_907Z_6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b_MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter_impl_js_11.call(2019-01-20T15:38:23.907Z/6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b/MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter-impl.js)  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2019_01_20T15_38_23_907Z_6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b_MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter_impl_js_11.call(2019-01-20T15:38:23.907Z/6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b/MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter-impl.js)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:267)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:241)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:211)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:124)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)  at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)  at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:593)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:539)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:58)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:433)  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:430)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:139)  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1274)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:767)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:469)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:217)  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:222)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:968)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1056)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:266)  at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:776)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
```

[ERROR  ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure [project DM]MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E: parameters: [project DM]  Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty  FWLSE0101E: Caused by: [project DM]**javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-emptyjava.lang.RuntimeException**: Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:236)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:185)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:169)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:145)  at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:134)  at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)  at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:593)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:539)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:58)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:433)  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:430)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:496)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:480)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:131)  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor208.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)  at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_12(/integration.js:103)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2019_01_20T15_38_23_907Z_6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b_MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter_impl_js_11._c_registerPublicUser_5(2019-01-20T15:38:23.907Z/6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b/MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter-impl.js:74)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2019_01_20T15_38_23_907Z_6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b_MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter_impl_js_11.call(2019-01-20T15:38:23.907Z/6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b/MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter-impl.js)  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2019_01_20T15_38_23_907Z_6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b_MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter_impl_js_11.call(2019-01-20T15:38:23.907Z/6fec582d2f5e101e2dcaa4dea7bb551f4188b75b/MissionskyiDubaiUMAdapter-impl.js)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:267)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:241)  at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:211)  at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:124)  at

Comment: The issue is happening when you calling the backend. The most likely cause is an empty trust store, no trust store, or it can't be opened.

Comment: @VivinK  do you mean, can I open the key store which defined in worklight.properties ?    ssl.keystore.path=conf/default.keystore

Answer (score 0):

you need to collect more data to solve the above error on WebSphere Liberty, so we need to apply The below steps.

```
•   SET UP LIBERTY FOR SSL TRACING : 

1.  Locate your jvm.options file
A.  The jvm.options files can be found under the following path:
<LIBERTY_HOME>/usr/servers/<server name>/jvm.options
     If the jvm.options file does not exist, create it with a text editor.
B.  Insert the following generic JVM arguments to the jvm.options file:
-Djavax.net.debug=true
Make sure you do not have any extra white space in your jvm.options file.
C.  Save the changes to your jvm.options file.
Your changes will not be picked up by the JVM until the server is restarted.


2.  Set up the Liberty server for SSL tracing
•   Follow the instructions in the Enabling Trace on Liberty section in Set up trace and get a full dump for WebSphere Liberty. (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21596714)
•   Use the following trace string: SSLChannel=all:com.ibm.ws.ssl.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.ssl=all:com.ibm.wsspi.ssl.*=all


3.  Verify that your tracing is working as intended
A.  Stop the Liberty Server
B.  Delete any existing logs files found under the logs directory:
<LIBERTY_HOME>/usr/servers/<serverName>/logs
C.  Restart the Liberty Server and review the logs to confirm that they are recent.
D.  Verify that the new Liberty trace setting has been picked up by reviewing the upper part of the trace.log file.
```

Please watch this video will explain step by step the above points.
•   https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=183&v=VSAEgiGez3w